# Vector of pointers in different methods of the same class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I need a vector that can store classes (`B`) that inherit from `A`. The vector is in a class that manages all the flow of the application and contains the vector `Test`.

Class A

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void test() {
        cout << "Class A" << endl;
    }
};
```

Class B

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void test() {
        cout << "Class B" << endl;
    }
};
```

Test class

```
class Test {
private:
    vector<A*> v;
public:
    void input() {
        A a;
        B b;
        A *a2 = &b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i%2 > 0) {
                    v.push_back(&a);
            } else {
                    v.push_back(a2);
            }
        }
}
    void output() {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            v[i]->test();
        }
    }
};
```

main

```
int main () {
    Test t;
    t.input();
    t.output();
    return 0;
}
```

This program adds the classes **B A B A B A B A B A** to the vector, and outputs "Class A" or "Class B" deppending on what class is.

If i put the code of the `output()` inside the `input()` method, the program works fine. But as it is here, the program compiles without problem, but it gives an Access Violation error on execution.
This is a simplification of a bigger problem. I prefer not to have all the code of the `output()` method in the `input()` method.

From what I see, from method to method, the pointers of the vector are corrupted and don't point correctly. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are operating on the objects which are created on stack in the `input` method which are destroyed after the method is returned.
Even though you store the address of those objects in the vector and try to access them in the `output` method your program crashes because those objects are no more existent.

Instead create the objects in `main` or create them dynamically on heap.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I'm not too used to work with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

These definitions

```
A a;
B b;
```

define local variables of function input which will be destroyed after exiting the function. The pointers became invalid. You should dynamically allocate objects that will be added to the vector.